# Whats going on with the dot (.) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I'm having trouble understanding how the function composition operator works in Haskell. I understand it in simple cases where you only use functions that takes one argument but I don't understand whats going on when you use it on several functions that each take more than one argument.

Consider this function:

```
f1 = (*) . (+) 2 $ 1
```

All this function does is that it takes a number and multiplies it with three so it's the same as:

```
f2 = (*) $ (+) 2 1
```

and

```
f3 = (*) 3
```

I understand exactly whats going on in f2 but I dont get what is going on in f1 that makes the two the same. The (.) takes two functions and a value, each of the functions can only take one argument so in this case both (*) and (+) has to be partially applied for things to work. What I don't understand is what they are applied to and how this is sent through the chain of functions.

In f2 (+) is first applied to both funtions producing a value that is partially applied to (*), creating a function. In f1 it is not possible for (+) to be assigned to both values since (.) requires a function as input, yet they are the same. I do not understand this.

I hope you understand what I'm having problems understanding. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Join the club! Some folks are really adept at understanding these weird function compositions. Some of us not so much. I haven't found it to be a big obstacle in the long term, so I would just not worry about this too much...

Comment: I actually don't care that much, my professor does ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of order of operations, Haskell generally goes: Parentheses, Function Applications, Operators, Special Forms. So `fact 8 + case h (f 3 + g 1) of Nothing -> 2` will parse as:

```
(+)
    fact
        8
    case
        h
            (+)
                f
                    3
                g
                    1
            Nothing
            2
```

with both the `f` and `g` happening first. In terms of multiple functions, `f g h` is implicitly `(f g) h` -- this is called a "left-associative" law, but I like to call it "the law of greedy nom": a function consumes ("noms") whatever single thing is immediately in front of it without waiting and is satisfied. (Well -- it may produce a function which takes another argument, of course...)

Your two functions' parse trees are:

```
f1 = (*) . (+) 2 $ 1
($)
    (.)
        (*)
        (+)
            2
    1

f2 = (*) $ (+) 2 1
($)
    (*)
    (+)
        2
        1
```

We of course know that `a $ b = a b` is the definition of `$` and `a . b = \x -> a (b x)` is the definition of `.`. From this we see the deep identity that:

```
(a . b) c == a $ b c
```

(the `$` function can be thought of as "lazy nom", I am saying that `a` will consume the entire rest of the expression as its argument.)

In other words, function application converts a `.` into a `$`. That is actually all that you need to understand the above expression:

```
(*) . (+) 2 $ 1
--> ((*) . (+) 2) 1  [use explicit () instead of the precedence of $]
--> (*) $ (+) 2 1  [your expression]
```

Intuitively, the `(*) . (2 +)` above says "take the output of `(2 +)` and feed it into the input of `(*)`. If you feed `4` to the result, the first thing which happens is that it computes `2 + 4`, outputting `6`, and then this is fed into the input of `(*)` to make `(6 *)`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the operator precedence might help:

```
f1 = ((*) . ((+) 2)) $ 1
```

In other words, it’s `(*)` of `(2+)` – that is, `\x -> (*) ((2+) x)` – on `1`, making it `(*) ((2+) 1)`, which is `(*) (2 + 1)`, which is `(*) 3`, and that’s `f2`.

Answer (score 3):

`(.)` is just another function in Haskell:

```
(.) f g x = f (g x)
```

both `f` and `g` may expect more than one arguments, by the way. This means that

```
(f . g) = (.) f g = (\x -> f (g x))         -- !!
```

This is the key: any (last) argument on left hand side of a Haskell equational definition can go to the right hand side, where it becomes a (first) lambda parameter.

So,

```
f1 = (*) . (+) 2 $ 1
   = ((*) . ((+) 2)) 1            -- this is how it is really read
   = (\x -> (*) ( ((+) 2) x )) 1
   =        (*) ( ((+) 2) 1 )
   =        (*) (  (+) 2  1 )
   =        (*) 3
```

No mysteries there, really.

Answer (score 2):

As @minitech points out, first understand the order of operations, i.e.:

```
f1 = ((*) . ((+) 2)) $ 1
```

In general, for binary operations `f` and `g`, this equality is true:

```
((f . (g x)) $ y) z = f (g x y) z
```

We just use the definition of the compose operator: `(f . g) a = f (g a)`.

```
 (f . (g x)) $ y = (f . (g x)) y = f (g x y)
```

and so:

```
 ((f . (g x)) $ y) z = f (g x y) z
```

Now substitute `f = (*)`, `g = (+)`, `x = 2` and `y = 1`.